# Выравнивание элементов по ширине

Tags: jquery

Для выравнивания блоков по высоте есть jQuery плагины, интересует, если что что-то подобное для выравнивания блоков/элементов по ширине.

На несколько страниц из галереи выводятся изображения, они имеют разную ширину. Число изображений в ряду и число рядов не фиксировано. 
То есть сейчас выводится как на первой картинке, а нужно, чтобы было как на второй.

[image: layout1]
[image: layout1]

Пока нашла что-то вроде такого: [выравнивание изображений с помощью jquery](http://boxxystyle.ru/2012/05/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-jquery/), но там отвалилось демо, так что пока еще не совсем понятно, какой будет итоговый результат.
Но может кто еще чего встречал/использовал в своей практике?

Comment: Ваши изображения требуют регистрации на форуме, переложите их куда-нибудь.

Comment: а как сейчас?

Comment: @Heidel, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: э, вообще-то, я не просила что-то за меня решать, а спросила о том, не известно ли кому о же существующих плагинах для решения этой задачи, потому что я в поиске нашла только один подобный.

Comment: [Демо расширения](http://jsfiddle.net/gzKdV/2/) по приведенной ссылке.

PS Не вижу другого решения, кроме как жестко задавать количество столбцов.